# skip lines if something is true

Tags: java, if-statement, skip

I´m currently working on a calculator and i want to skip 2 lines of my code if the second Scan equals a specific word. In this case the word is either "Wurzel" or "wurzel" because i wont need to scan b then.

```
    Scanner eingabe = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigInteger a, b, ergebnis;
    String Operator;
    System.out.println("Bitte gib die erste Zahl ein:");
    a = eingabe.nextBigInteger();
    System.out.println("Bitte gib die Rechenart ein:");
    Operator = eingabe.next();
    if(Operator == "Wurzel" || Operator == "wurzel" ) {
        //skip to switch(operator)
    }
    System.out.println("Bitte gib die zweite Zahl ein:");
    b = eingabe.nextBigInteger();
    switch(Operator) {
       ...
     }
```

Comment: Can't use == on strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should negate the if statement and put the pieces in the middle inside that block.

```
if(!( Operator.equals("Wurzel") || Operator.equals("wurzel") ) {
    System.out.println("Bitte gib die zweite Zahl ein:");
    b = eingabe.nextBigInteger();    
}
```